# How to scroll the user at the exact position, which is somewhere between two views.?

Tags: android, scroll, pagination, android-recyclerview

Actually i am implementing a recyclerview in android now i am facing a problem that when i do pagination(scrolling) then i want to scroll the user to the exact position where user was before pagination but what happens is that when i use scrollto() method it scroll to some pixels above or sometimes some pixels beow but not at the exact position.

**As in order to restructure my problem** i want to ask is, is there any possible way by which i can check how many pixel down was the user at any position, because for example user can be somewhere between the 10 and 11 but i will scroll him to 10 or 11 but i want to scroll him at exact between 10 and 11 where he was can anyone please enlighten me i am trying so hard but i am not able to figure it out how to do this.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972184/android-get-the-exact-position-on-the-screen-that-the-user-was-at-in-a-recycler/32992638#32992638)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somehow not clear but try to cover it up,

You should use:

```
LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(int, int)
```

This will scroll your view to the specific position.